# How to restart the network manager applet

Tags: wireless, network-manager, indicator, applet

Sometimes my network manager indicator (applet) shows as if I'm not connected to wifi (no bars) and when I right click it it says "networking disabled" **although I am connected to the internet**. Maybe it's a bug or something.

Running `sudo service network-manager restart` fixes this applet. It restarts the whole network. Does anyone know a simple way to restart just the applet? (`nm-applet`)

Comment: Is there a bug in Launchpad for this issue that we can follow? I'm more interested in "curing the disease" than "treating the symptom", so to speak.

Comment: I have the same problem in 16.04, and `sudo service network-manager restart` doesn't always fix it. For example, now the indicator shows zero "bars" and no network, even though I'm online typing this comment. [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/K1gemon).

Comment: @DanDascalescu see the accepted answer. use `killall nm-applet; nohup nm-applet &`

Comment: @MinaMichael Thank you for the hint about `sudo service ____ restart` !!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can restart **nm-applet** with this command from terminal:

```
killall nm-applet; nohup nm-applet &
```

or by restarting the network-manager service (which will restart nm-applet):

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

or

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

In new Ubuntu 22.04 versions and upper:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

---

**[Here](https://youtu.be/pwXBk7f5gow)  is a YouTube video explaining the answer**.

Comment: Perfect -- working on 16.04 still.

Comment: does the trick on 16.10 as well, fixing the not discovering new wifi on the xps 13

Comment: it doesn't work on 16.10. the app restarts but it does not show in taskbar. only works by restarting network-manager service. after killing nm-applet, not even restarting network manager shows it again, and I had to restart lightdm.

Comment: Worked on 16.04.2, while `sudo service network-manager restart` didn't (it led to the indicator showing zero "bars" and no network, even though I'm online typing this comment. [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/K1gemon).

Comment: but, how I can do the `killall nm-applet && nohup nm-applet &` automatically after resume ?

Comment: @YonsySolis I'll see if I can find the question and answer that covers that, but it is a udev or systemd power state rule IIRC.

Comment: I found `nm-applet` occupying the top 2 positions (sorted by CPU usage) in `htop` when I had a flaky Internet connection.  The `killall` method seems to have cured both problems, thank you!

Comment: `killall nm-applet && nohup nm-applet & && disown` -- Add disown to unhook executed job from the running shell.

Answer (score 2):

If you have gnome, restarting the shell (Alt-F2, r, Return) might do it.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for me. Btw I stated I'm on LXDE which is not gnome

Comment: I shouldn't try that  when Pycharm/Chrome/A few ssh session are opened...

Answer (score 0):

None of the accepted answer's suggestions worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04.5, but this did:

```
sudo killall -9 nm-applet && nm-applet &
```

The main difference seems to be `sudo` before `killall`.